# Let $f(x,y)=\dfrac {x^2}{y^4} e^{\frac{-x^2}{y^4}}.$ If $y \neq 0$ and $f(x,0)=0$, is $f$ differentiable at $(0,0)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x,y)=\dfrac {x^2}{y^4}e^{\frac{-x^2}{y^4}}.$

I need to check if this equation is differentiable at $(0,0),$ if $y$ different than $0$ and $f(x,0)=0$.

A very simmilar question is on my exams. Can you help me solve this one?

Comment: What have you tried?  What are the rules for checking for differentiability?  Have you attempted to apply them?  What did you get?

Comment: Do you mean $$f(x,y) = \frac {x^2}{y^4} e^{-x^2/y^4}$$

Comment: @PeteBabe yes thats what i mean.

Comment: @DanUznanski Maths is not my major. i just want to learn the basic steps to be able to recreate them. Usually the exams are very similar. Thanks for the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that for $x=t^2$ and $y=t \to 0$

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \dfrac {x^2}{y^4}e^{-x^2/y^4}= \lim_{t \to 0} e^{-1}= \frac 1e$$

and for $x=2t^2$ and $y=t \to 0$

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \dfrac {x^2}{y^4}e^{-x^2/y^4}= \lim_{t \to 0} 4e^{-4}= \frac 4{e^4}$$

therefore the function is not continuous at $(0,0)$ and therefore it can't be differentiable at that point.

Comment: Alternatively, for the second limit you can look along the path $t\mapsto (t,0)$. It's simpler to notice it will give a different result.

Comment: @Ennar Yes of course! This is really a very discontinuous funtion :)

Answer (score 0):

Similar idea to what user used in their answer, but a bit differently flavored. Define $g(t) = f(t^2,t)$. If $f$ were continuous at $(0,0)$, $g$ would be continuous at $0$ (composition of continuous functions is continuous). However,

$$ g(t) = 
\begin{cases}
e^{-1},& t\neq 0,\\
0,& t = 0,
\end{cases}$$

which is obviously not continuous at $0$, so $f$ is not continous at $(0,0)$.